# Send a file to REST API in java

Tags: java, web-services, rest, file, multipart

My requirement is to send a audio file from java script to REST web service where i will process the file. My implementation code is below. But it is very slow. Any pointers how to speed up this rest call?

Client Code :

```
var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append("file", file);
                $http(
                        {
                            url : 'url,
                            method : "POST",
                            data : formData,
                            headers : {
                                'Content-Type' : undefined
                            }
                        })
                        .success(
                                function(data, status, headers,
                                        config) {
                                    successCallback(data, status,
                                            headers, config);
                                })
                        .error(
                                function(data, status, headers,
                                        config) {
                                    alert("ERROR: Could not send audio.");
                                });
```

Rest API:

```
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Path("/respapipath/")
    public void processTheFile(@Multipart("file") Attachment file){
//some logic
}
```